# Should entity contain only behavior that modifies the state?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I had a discussion recently with a co-worker, where he insisted that in Domain-Driven Design entities should not have a behavior that does not modify its state. In my experience to date, I never heard about this limitation. Is it a valid DDD rule?

To give some context (simplified scenario) - in our domain we have Computer entity, on which you can start Processes, our integration layer will actually delegate it to a remote physical Computer and start a process there.

So, should `StartProcess` be a behaviour of a `Computer` entity? Or should it be included in Domain Service as it does not affect the state of the `Computer` entity directly? (it modifies the state indirectly as once the process is over, and data is synchronized back to our system).

To me Entity is a natural place for it, as it follows the ubiquitous language, but I am wondering if someone has good reasons against (or other reasons for).

Answer (score 2):

IMO an entity behavior does not need to modify state, but at the very least should emit an event. In this case, the event would be something like `ProcessStarted`. CQRS/event-sourcing views aggregates essentially as command handlers - they handle commands and emit events. State  is made explicit when required for behavior or when denormalized for query purposes.

Comment: I want just to mention that while a message driven architecture and CQRS fit so well DDD, they aren't required

Comment: True, though use of domain events doesn't imply CQRS/ES. I should have been more clear.